# Google InAppBilling onPurchaseStateChange is never called

Tags: android, billing

The call back method `onPurchaseStateChange` is never called. I did my own demo-app and also tried using the Google provided demo (Dungeons).

I'm calling `requestPurchase(String productId, String payload)` from the `onClick` method.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == requestPurchaseButton) {
            mBillingService.requestPurchase("android.test.purchased", "10");
        }
    }
```

The callback method `onRequestPurchaseResponse(Request, ResponseCode)` is called.
The `responseCode` here gives the value `RESULT_OK`. So the request has been sent to the server.

```
       @Override
       public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request,
                ResponseCode responseCode) 
       {
              if(responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("AJ", "onRequestPurchaseResponse.ResponeCode.RESULT_OK");
            textView.append(request.mProductId + "\n");
          } else if(responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_USER_CANCELED) {
                      //doesn't go here
          } else { 
                     //doesn't go here
          }
       }
```

The javadoc for this method states

> This is called when we receive a response code from Market for a RequestPurchase request that we made. This is NOT used for any purchase state changes. All purchase state changes are received in onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState, String, int, long). This is used for reporting various errors, or if the user backed out and didn't purchase the item. The possible response codes are: RESULT_OK means that the order was sent successfully to the server. The onPurchaseStateChange() will be invoked later (with a purchase state of PURCHASED or CANCELED) when the order is charged or canceled. This response code can also happen if an order for a Market-managed item was already sent to the server. RESULT_USER_CANCELED means that the user didn't buy the item. RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE means that we couldn't connect to the Android Market server (for example if the data connection is down). RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE means that in-app billing is not supported yet. RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE means that the item this app offered for sale does not exist (or is not published) in the server-side catalog. RESULT_ERROR is used for any other errors (such as a server error).

But the callback method

```
    @Override
        public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState,
                String itemId, int quantity, long purchaseTime,
                String developerPayload) {
            Log.d("AJ", "onPurchaseStateChanged");

        }
```

is never called.

Am I missing something? The same thing is being done in Dungeons (Google provided demo) and the `onPurchaseStateChange` is not called.

The [Test-InAppBilling](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html) document shows that we must be able to reach Purchased state. But When I try, I see only

> android.test.purchased: sending purchase request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having this same problem but just solved it for myself.  I was using my work's public key in the code, but trying to run the app on my personal phone.  Since I was signed in on my phone with my personal account, I'm guessing Google rightly assumed I wasn't the developer.  I would think they would send an error message back though.  Once I plugged my personal key into the code, it worked fine on my phone.  So the key's may not be matching for you as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, wasn't checking on sat/sun. Would you plz elaborate on where i need to put this code. I haven't yet created a google-inAppBilling test account, i thgt that for testing the prededined values (i'm currently passing "android.test.purchased") i don't need an account. I went thru the code and didn't find any  place where it requested a app-key or dev-key.  Thanks .

Comment: found it, but still not going to "onPurchaseStateChanged" :(

Comment: Where is your receiver for the broadcast intents? Put some log in there, doing mBillingService.requestPurchase should send you back RESPONSE_CODE then IN_APP_NOTIFY. Here's another Tutorial: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-payment-t52060.html for another perspective

Comment: If using the sample Dungeons code as a base, the key goes in the Security.java file on the line which starts:
**String base64EncodedPublicKey = ...**
This key must match the one on your dev account, as well as the Google account tied to the phone.

Comment: @Blundell : Yeah, thats exactly my problem. First i get the RESPONSE_CODE, then i'm not getting IN_APP_NOTIFY, instead i get RESPONSE_CODE again. The log output is

Comment: DEBUG/BillingService(1273): request id: 7699564216586452225
INFO/BillingService(1273): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
DEBUG/BillingService(1273): RequestPurchase: RESULT_OK
DEBUG/Dungeons(1273): android.test.purchased: RESULT_OK
INFO/Dungeons(1273): purchase was successfully sent to server
INFO/BillingService(1273): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
DEBUG/BillingService(1273): GetPurchaseInformation: RESULT_ERROR

Comment: I'm checking this app from India, Is that a problem, as it is not a supported country for merchants. [SOURCE](https://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=150324)

Comment: I dont need to upload the test app as a draft right? Dungeons or InAppPurchaseTwo. Sorry for so many posts, i'm reading lots of stuff and getting doubts and google isn't providing good support. Thanks guys

Comment: No if your using the purchase item android.test.purchased you do not need to upload this to the market. What version of the Android Market is the phone your testing on?

Comment: I'm using market version 2.3.4. And me testing it from India isn't an issue right? I should still be able to check for android.test.purchased ?

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for all your help. Really just needed to log-in with the publisher account. I was using a test account which was added in the publisher site, dunno why that wasn't working tho. I think i have it figured out now. StackOverFlow - 1, Google - 0 wrt to support for their stuff. Thanks a lot again. Woot.

Comment: So am I getting it right, that when published you don´t need the base64... key in the security.java?