# InAppBilling activity and finish()

Tags: java, android, billing

I'm having lots of trouble with integrating google's In-App-Billing.

I have an activity which is supposed to do the In-App-Billing. I'm calling this activity from my main activity using the startActivity method.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.mypackage.mainactivity","com.mypackage.mainactivity.InAppBillingActivity"));                
startActivity(i);
```

and calling `mBillingService.requestPurchase("android.test.purchased", "10")`
in the onCreate method on In-App-Billing activity.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mInAppBillingPurchaseObserver = new InAppBillingPurchaseObserver(mHandler);
        mBillingService = new BillingService();
        mBillingService.setContext(this);

        ResponseHandler.register(mInAppBillingPurchaseObserver);
        boolean supported = mBillingService.checkBillingSupported();
        System.out.println("onCreate.isBillingSupported " + supported);
        if(supported) {
            Log.i("AJ", "Calling requestPurchase");
            mBillingService.requestPurchase("android.test.purchased", "10");
        }
    }
```

Since In-App-Billing makes an asynchronous call to the server, when should i call finish() to return to the main activity. But i dont want the activity to end, i still need the results of the async call made. So how do i go about handling that.

I called the finish() after sending the request to the server. But then i got this exception :

```
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549): Activity com.mypackage.mainactivity.InAppBillingActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.mypackage.mainactivity.BillingService@45b0ad50 that was originally bound here
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.mypackage.mainactivity.InAppBillingActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.mypackage.mainactivity.BillingService@45b0ad50 that was originally bound here
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.(ActivityThread.java:1158)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:1053)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:908)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at com.mypackage.mainactivity.BillingService.bindToMarketBillingService(Unknown Source)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at com.mypackage.mainactivity.BillingService.access$000(Unknown Source)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at com.mypackage.mainactivity.BillingService$BillingRequest.runRequest(Unknown Source)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at com.mypackage.mainactivity.BillingService.checkBillingSupported(Unknown Source)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at com.mypackage.mainactivity.InAppBillingActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2701)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2107)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-29 03:11:58.897: ERROR/ActivityThread(3549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It didn't exit the application, but it stopped the InAppBillingActivity.

Any help is most appreciated.

Thanks,
AkasH

P.S.: [My Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429345/google-inappbilling-onpurchasestatechange-is-never-called), still unsolved.....

Comment: You can't call finish after sending a purchase request, as the Market Intent needs to be fired with the Activity context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `startActivityForResult()`
[Context.StartActivityforResult URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

That way you can start your billing, let it do it's Async callbacks and when it has received the 'success' or 'fail' you can call finish(); sending back the result.

Another Tutorial for In App Billing is : [Simple InApp Billing](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-payment-t52060.html) , this gives you a second perspective and might help you come to terms with what the BillingService is trying to achieve.

*EDIT*

For your error with 'Simple InApp Billin':
You are getting an error in your purchase, you could catch this in the Billing Service where it is returning false, otherwise in the Billing Helper you can update the method to stop this:

```
 protected static void verifyPurchase(String signedData, String signature) {
            ArrayList<VerifiedPurchase> purchases = BillingSecurity.verifyPurchase(signedData, signature);
            if(purchases != null && !purchases.isEmpty()){ // Check for NPE
                    latestPurchase = purchases.get(0);

                    confirmTransaction(new String[]{latestPurchase.notificationId});
            } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BillingHelper.verifyPurchase error. purchases was null");
            }

            if(mCompletedHandler != null){
                    mCompletedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "verifyPurchase error. Handler not instantiated. Have you called setCompletedHandler()?");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that link. I'm going through it right now. But even if we start a new activity by calling startActivityForResult(), how can we come back to the calling activity without finishing the called activity. For eg, A calls B. without finishing B, can i get back to A and let B run in the background. I got the error as saying, result is not being returned or something when using startActivityForResult().

Comment: If you want B to run in the background, it should do this in a service not an Activity.

Comment: I downloaded the test app from anddev, and changed the public key. But i'm getting the error

Comment: Yeah, so instead of creating a new activity, i'll launch the service from my activity itself :) . I downloaded the test app from anddev, and changed the public key. But i'm getting the error [The log file](http://files.foraster.us/download.php?file=58d5d94124e5531812070ce008e1867f), any idea why that maybe??

Comment: You seem to have got your public key wrong. BillingSecurity Line 137ish it is failing validation.

Comment: I checked the public-key, it is correct, but the BillingSecurity.verify method is returning false. That is causing a NullPointerException in BillingHelper.verifyPurchase method @lines latestPurchase = purchases.get(0); confirmTransaction(new String[]{latestPurchase.notificationId});if(mCompletedHandler != null){
    mCompletedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
   } else {
    Log.e(TAG, "verifyPurchase error. Handler not instantiated.");
   }. And the Handler in AppMainTest class. Maybe both are related...If you get any idea as to why i'm getting this exception, please post it here. Thanks a ton

Comment: Changed the verifyPurchase method to catch this, updated my answer

Comment: Modified that function and added a try-catch block to the Handler in AppMainTest. The NPE maybe coming from the handleMessage block. I have uploaded the log [HERE](http://files.foraster.us/download.php?file=1732d1cf0f7aabe3ec178521113873dd).

Comment: Please read your stack trace, it's telling you the error's :-) "Signature verification failed." "signature does not match data." "NullPointerException com.blundell.test.AppMainTest.handleMessage() line number: 44"

Comment: I got through that problem, now i wrote my own Activity for doing an In-app purchase, but it says "RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" (Indicates that the network connection is down). When i run dungeons or InAppPurchaseTut, its working fine. T_T. In the logs it says "ERROR/vending(2203): [20] RequestRunnable.run(): Got ApiException from async request: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.AckNotificationsRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST". If was missing any parameters, i should get DEVELOPER_ERROR. I think i will make a new question, with full details. As the char limit here is less.

Comment: aaaaaaaah I don't understand why Google made is so hard to implement in-app payments. Paypal integration is more easy than this... going to Paypal bye bye in-app payments.